# Error while mutating Uid : [X] cannot be greater than lease: [Y]

Tags: neo4j, directed-graph, dgraph

I am trying to load a 2million records in dgraph, each is structured like

```
message_id : <>
message_id_replied_to: <references message_id>
```

I process them like

1. Load all `message_ids` in dgraph using bulk loader
2. Then start processing `message_id_replied_to` , if value of `message_id_replied_to` exists in exisitng nodes, I create a RDF using that uid.
3. Then using `liveloader` I insert all `message_id_replied_to` links (predicates)

Now for running in another machine,

1. I copy `out` directory which I got after step 1, start alphas using
   it.
2. Then the RDF file generated after step 2, which looks like
   `<0x15f91> <message_id_replied_to>  <0x70271b> .` and `liveload` it

I am assuming `p` directory in `out` file maintains same `uid` and so this liveload will work

The problem is liveloading second time it says 
`Error while mutating Uid: [430060] cannot be greater than lease: [10000]` and I didn't `zw` directory

Also is this approach correct? will it work if i keep a copy of `zw` too?`enter code here`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the Dgraph Bulk Loader you **must use the same Zero** (i.e., the same zw directory) you used for bulk loading. Dgraph Zero hands out UID leases used for UID assignment during the bulk load, so using a brand-new Zero would result in the error "[430060] cannot be greater than lease: [10000]".

I recommend following the Dgraph docs about the bulk loader: https://docs.dgraph.io/deploy#bulk-loader.